# .net 4 routing rule help

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have below rule

```
routes.MapPageRoute("file",
       "f/{Id}",
       "~/file.aspx"
    );
```

it works just fine if I request **site.com/f/11** but when I request **site.com/f/11&foo=foo** it fails. is there anyway changing this rule so it would ignore **& - = - ?**

Comment: Shouldn't you be requesting the URL `site.com/f/11?foo=foo` instead?

Comment: problem is that google some how indexed some parts of site from old design as in my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using a URL like this: `site.com/f/11?foo=foo&anotherparam=anothervalue`